# How can I add layer from other view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
UITextView *text = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
[text setText:@"hello world!"];
text.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

[self.layer addSublayer:text.layer];
```

I just can see blue,why?

Comment: you set text.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; thats why showing blue.instead of that set text.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: @karboom : let me know what is your requirement, or what you mean.

Comment: I want to add layer from other view's layer to make some animation @Vineesh TP

Comment: You can create new CALayer with your requirement and add to your layer.

Comment: As per doc, layers do not have appearance. Can you please describe what kind of animation you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see only blue color only means change your text color by `text.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];`

**Eg:**

```
UITextView *text = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
[text setText:@"hello world!"];
text.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
text.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to mess with the hierarchy of a layer that’s owned by a view. Just add the view as a subview:

```
[self addSubview:text];
```